# How to store an Express session in a MongoDB database using a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, session

I have a controller that can handle a user login and store the session, but I noticed the session is not being stored even after I have initialized the express session to use this code

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: store,
})).
```

This is my mongostore code

```
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp', 
  databaseName: 'myapp',
  collection: 'mySessions',

  // Change the expires key name
  expiresKey: `_ts`,
  // This controls the life of the document - set to same value as expires / 1000
  expiresAfterSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 14 
});
```

I was expecting to store the session id and then log the user in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store an Express session in a MongoDB database using a controller, you can use the `express-session` middleware along with the `connect-mongodb-session` module. Here are the steps:

1. Install the `express-session` and `connect-mongodb-session` modules using npm:

```bash
npm install express-session connect-mongodb-session
```

2. In your controller file, require both modules:

```js
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
```

3. Create a new instance of `MongoDBStore`:

```js
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp',
  collection: 'mySessions'
});
```

In this example, the `uri` option specifies the MongoDB connection string, and the `collection` option specifies the name of the collection where the sessions will be stored.

4. Configure the `express-session` middleware to use the MongoDB store:

```js
app.use(session({
  secret: 'my secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true },
  store: store
}));
```

In this example, the `secret` option is a string used to sign the session ID cookie, the `resave` option specifies whether to save the session to the store on every request, the `saveUninitialized` option specifies whether to save uninitialized sessions, the `cookie` option specifies the session cookie settings, and the `store` option specifies the MongoDB store.

5. Use the session in your controller routes:

```js
router.get('/myroute', (req, res) => {
  req.session.username = 'johndoe';
  res.send('Session stored in MongoDB!');
});
```

In this example, the `username` property is added to the session object, and the response sends a message indicating that the session was stored successfully.

By following these steps, you can store an Express session in a MongoDB database using a controller.

Comment: Thank you @Md the solution only worked to stop the errors, but I figured out that because my site is still in production mode, I couldn't store user sessions but when I get a domain with an SSL certificate it is going to store user sessions.